# save downloaded image to camera roll with PHPhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, phasset

I triggered a background download of an image. It succeeds - location is a path to the actual image. I get no error message, but also the image does NOT show up in the photos app. I have set the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription Info.plist key. The app has rights to access the photos. I know, this code triggers another background thread, but that shouldn't be a problem, because the "location" file is still there after "didFinishDownloadingTo" finished. Is there anything else to take care of when storing JPG files to the camera roll?

```
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            print("starting")
            let req = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
            req.isFavorite = true;

            let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions();
            options.shouldMoveFile = true;

            req.addResource(with: PHAssetResourceType.photo, fileURL: location, options: options)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `addResource` incorrectly. What you have is not a resource; it's the image. So first, load the data from the URL and turn it into an image:

```
if let url = location, let d = try? Data(contentsOf:url) {
    let im = UIImage(data:d)
}
```

Now just add the image as an asset:

```
     PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
         PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: im!)
     })
```

One you've persuaded yourself that that works, you can start dressing it up.

Comment: "didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL" downloads a JPG from my server. I would rather store this raw jpg image than decoding and encoding it again. But I will check if your UIImage alternative works. Thanks!

Comment: The debugger does not stop for any code line within performChanges. I guess that's why using UIImage did not make a difference so far. I don't have any clue why this code block is not executing.

Comment: I'm not understanding. Notice the order in which I'm doing things; I extract the UIImage _immediately_, because it will be destroyed otherwise. Are you doing what I said? Is the UIImage extracted? Is `performChanges` called? If you're on a background thread, does stepping out to main thread help?

Comment: Well, you can create the PHAsset in 3 different ways. #1: From fileLocationUrl, #2: from UIImage and #3 from NSData. I was trying to get #1 working all day and failed. It turned out that only #2 and #3 work in my scenario. I will now use #3 and create my PHAsset from NSData, because that way I will keep all exif data and there is hopefully no re-encoding. Thanks Matt for suggesting #2 which let me realise that my code is not totally wrong. :) I have still no clue why #1 does not work, but that's irrelevant.